# Terminate Room database procedure android

Tags: android, sqlite

i have a question about a specific example in android. Lets say iam running a Room database insertion within a thread/asyncTask.

```
Thread
{
  mDatabase.repoMethods().insert1
  mDatabase.repoMethods().insert2
  mDatabase.repoMethods().insert3                    
}
```

If i stop the thread when the insertion is happening what is the end result?
For the sake of the example lets say i stop the thread when insertion1 is happening. Will it complete first and then terminate? or it will execute the other insertions and then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer this question in an investigative manner because I wasn't sure about the answer so I did some research. Some of the facts are assumptions drawn from the knowledge I have of SQL. So anyone, feel free to correct me. There are two things in this question:

**1)** First is the interrupted `insert` query. `Room` is just an abstraction layer over **SQLite**, and **SQLite** follows [ACID](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/sqlite/sqlite-acid-transactions) properties. In your case what concerns us is the **A**tomicity:

> Atomicity means all the operations of transaction must be finished or rollback the complete transaction in case of any failures.

**2)** Second is the interrupted `Thread`, **but** if a `Thread` is interrupted using `Thread.interrupt()` it will not affect the query as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17813112/7915814) and to some extent [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459493/android-how-cancel-interrupt-break-pending-sqlite-query/6263556). Therefore the first `insert` will be executed and only then the `Thread` will be interrupted.

Thinking logically, if for some reason the query is interrupted [somehow](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/interrupt.html) (I'm not sure how it translates to Java), then the Atomicity of SQLite will make sure to abort the transaction.